# How do you deal with route-based urls?

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, symfony-2.3

Let's say we have a collection of entities, like `articles` and we need to generate a list of it with the corresponding urls to a particular article.

If we didn't use angularjs then a list item could look like (twig):

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ path('article', {'id': article.id}) }}">{{ article.name }}</a>
</li>
```

But, because of I'm using angularjs - I cannot use this solution since I iterate over articles on client side and don't have access to server side url generator.

I've came into 2 conclusions:

1. (the one I use) I generate the url with `id: 0` and then in angularjs controller just replace `0` which acts as a placeholder with an actual id value
2. To generate an array of urls serverside and pass it into angularjs

I don't like any of the solutions much though.

Are there better options?

Comment: There is this [JSRoutingBundle bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) or you could look into creating a custom Javascript compiler that would replace patterns into routes (could be a great open source bundle).

Comment: @Thomas Potaire: FOSJsRoutingBundle is actually a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Friends of Symfony bundle [FoSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle).

Comment: Do you know how FOSRouting bundle deal with security about an exposed route? Does anuser can find with all the routes exposed by simpling searching in the javascript? If i'm on my user pages, can he found my admin pages exposed?

Comment: You can set routes to be exposed or not, see the [README.md](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/README.markdown#usage). The documentation is very light, the not sure if there are more features in the bundle. An alternative would be to look into creating a custom JS compiler.